# AWS Lambda Function Invoke on S3 event from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have created Lambda function with CLI command

```
aws lambda create-function 
   --function-name "functionName" 
   --runtime "java8" 
   --role "roleARN" 
   --handler "com.company.package.S3FileCreator::createFile"
   --zip-file "fileb://./filePath.zip"
```

Now I want to create trigger this function if I put any object on my s3 bucket, 
I can create trigger from Amazon Console but is it possible to create Trigger from CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **Solved** with the following steps:

**Assign function name/s3 bucket name/rold ARN on variable**

```
FUNCTION_NAME=lambda-function-name
S3_BUCKE=s3_bucket_name
ROLE=AWS_role_ARN
```

**Create Lambda Function and get the ARN**

```
LAMBDA_ARN=$(aws lambda create-function --function-name "$FUNCTION_NAME" --runtime "java8"  --role "$ROLE" --handler "com.monsanto.aws.S3NotificationAgent::handleRequest"  --zip-file "fileb://./target/file_name.zip" | grep FunctionArn | cut -d'"' -f4)
```

**Get current AWS account Number**

```
AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account')
```

**Generate unique Statement id**

```
STATEMENT_ID="$(date +%s%3N)-stm-name"
```

**Give Permission to S3 bucket to invoke that lambda function**

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name "$FUNCTION_NAME"
--principal "s3.amazonaws.com" --statement-id "$STATEMENT_ID" --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --source-arn "arn:aws:s3:::$S3_BUCKET"
--source-account "$AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
```

**Prepare JSON parameter for put-bucket-notification(no space between)**

```
NOTIFICATION_CONFIGURATIONS='{"LambdaFunctionConfigurations":[{"Id":"'"$FUNCTION_NAME"'-event","LambdaFunctionArn":"'"$LAMBDA_ARN"'","Events":["s3:ObjectCreated:*"],"Filter":{"Key":{"FilterRules":[{"Name":"suffix","Value":"log"},{"Name":"prefix","Value":"logtest"}]}}}]}'
```

**Add the s3 event to invoke Lambda function**

```
aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket "$S3_BUCKET" 
--notification-configuration "$NOTIFICATION_CONFIGURATIONS"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will want to read over [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) about using Lambda with S3.

In order to have your lambda trigger whenever a file is uploaded to a particular S3 bucket, you will need to create a bucket notification on that S3 bucket. This bucket notification should activate on S3:ObjectCreated:Put, since you said you want it to activate any time you put an object.

Here's [an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html) of a bucket notification being set up with CLI, and here's something closer to what you might want to try. FYI I haven't tested this.

*your-bucket-notification-config.json*

```
 {
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
        {
            "Id": "your-chosen-id",
            "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:YOUR_REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:functionName",
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:Put"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And then you would run:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket your-bucket --notification-configuration file://your-bucket-notification-config.json
```